# How to write a funcion that counts amount of letters of a word and print it as pair of tuppels?

Tags: haskell

Im new in Haskell and im trying to write a function that does the similar work:

```
counter :: Stirng -> [(Integer, Char)]
```

input:

```
prelude> counter "hello"
```

output:

```
[(1,'h'),(1,'e'),(2,'l'),(1,'o')]
```

Thanks

Comment: Should it count consecutive characters or characters overall? What have you tried? Can you describe in English what you want it to do? If so, can you do it with pen and paper then transfer that algorithm over to Haskell?

Comment: I think the question is clear that you undrestand what i meant. I dont think a pen and paper needed to describe.

Comment: The skill of computer programming is mostly in discovering just how imprecise natural languages actually are. Don't be so confident that we understand what you mean -- one input/output pair does not a function make, especially given that in other comments you say that it doesn't even necessarily have to be exactly that output!

Comment: The pen and paper and clear description is to help **you**, not us. You can't write code if all you think is "I want to go from A to B", you have to think about **how** you can go from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [`Data.List.sort`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) and [`Data.List.group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function. They'll get you most of the way there:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]

>>> group "Mississippi"
[["M","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"]]
```

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]

>> sort "Mississippi"
"Miiiippssss"
```

Comment: The answer that this seems to be hinting or at least the naive implementation at wont actually produce the sample output provided on the sample input, since it will output in sorted order where the output provided does not.

Comment: @ÉamonnOlive if you don't want it sorted, don't use `sort`. This will mean only consecutive pairs will be grouped. It's not quite clear what behavior OP wanted, but performing a unique grouping without sorting is a) less efficient and b) much harder to write for what seems to me little tangible benefit.

Comment: It doesnt matter if the output is sorted or not, just counting duplicates. btw Data.List should be helpful and i will try to undrestand it.